# How to use more than two logical operators in iF expression of azure data factory or nested expression of IF condition in azure datafactory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am trying below code in expression block of if condition..but its saying error as :Function 'and' does not accept 5 arguments(s)

Code:
@and(equals(activity('Notebook1').output.runoutput.status,'Success'),equals(activity('Notebook2').output.runoutput.status,'Success'),equals(activity('Notebook3').output.runoutput.status,'Success'),equals(activity('Notebook4').output.runoutput.status,'Success'),equals(activity('Notebook5').output.runoutput.status,'Success'))

All the notebooks from 1 to 5 are being executed in true block of IF condition just connected before the above IF condition

My target is to check all the outputs of 5 notebooks if all the notebooks pass suscess message then it should go for 'True' block in IF condition else if any of the notebooks from 1 to 5 returns any message other than 'Success' the should go for Flase block of IF condition

Answer (score 0):

Error: Invalid, function 'and' does not accept 5 argument(s)

So you have to nest it:

```
@and(
    equals(activity('Notebook1').output.runoutput.status,'Success'),
    and(
        equals(activity('Notebook2').output.runoutput.status,'Success'),
        and(
            equals(activity('Notebook3').output.runoutput.status,'Success'),
            and(
                equals(activity('Notebook4').output.runoutput.status,'Success')
                ,equals(activity('Notebook5').output.runoutput.status,'Success')
            )
        )
    )
)
```